# Load User Function before external resources in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I am working on developing a new accordion for my client. Everything is working correctly in my local machine but I am having issue when the same thing is uploaded in jsfiddle.

I found that the issue is because the user defined function is loading after the external js files I have added.

This is my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/imsabarinath/rpq2w/12/

In this I have added a user function `detectBrowserClass`.I have also added 8 external js files and css files via the external resource tab. But when I run the code, it seems that the user function is loaded only after all the external resources are loaded. I inspected with firebug and it clearly shows the user function is loaded after the external resources

[image]

Is there any way I can load the user function `detectBrowserClass` before loading any of the external resources in jsfiddle; means before all the script tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the "External Resources" option, you can put the `script` tags in the HTML field, i.e. add them to the body.

Comment: It is working when I am adding like that, but jsfiddle shows warning that use JavaScript  and CSS panels for their corresponding files. Is there a way we can hide that /

Comment: What's the reason you want to hide it?

Comment: No problem. It is just to make sure that the client doesn't see the error or warning

Comment: I don't think you can hide it, that's why I was asking. But if you just want to show the result (i.e. the rendered HTML), you can can share a fullscreen version of it. Click on "Share" -> "Share full screen result". If someone else has to see the source, add a comment at the beginning of the HTML and explain why the scripts have to be there.

Comment: @FelixKling The "Share full screen result" provides a url like this: jsfiddle.net/user/fiddleID/embedded/result. If someone else has to see the source, you can modify that url to this: jsfiddle.net/user/fiddleID/embedded/html,css,js,result/. This will provide different tabs for the html, css, js and result. Of course, you can omit any of these and re-order them as you wish.

Comment: @Sabari My tests reveal that saving a jsfiddle removes the warning. Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Bfuuq/